# pool ball moving algorithm

Tags: java-me, midp

I am trying to move a pool ball in Java2ME. It is easy when the velocity is stable. I change the x and y coordinate of the ball according to x and y velocity. They are all integers. No problem. However a normal pool ball has to go first fast then slowdown and stop. Because the x and y coordinates of the ball are integers, I can't decrease the x and y velocity by percentage. I mean if the velocity is 9 and I want to decrease it by 10% I cant do it "9 * 0.1" because it has to be an integer. I know the coordinates can't be double. What can I do?
the code:

```
public void move() {
    //... Move the ball at the given velocity.
    m_x += m_velocityX; // m_x: x coordinate of the ball
    m_y += m_velocityY; // m_y: y coordinate of the ball


    //... ball hits the borders and change the way
    if (m_x < 0) {                  // If at or beyond left side
        m_x         = 0;            // Place against edge and
        m_velocityX = -m_velocityX; // reverse direction.

    } else if (m_x > m_rightBound) { // If at or beyond right side
        m_x         = m_rightBound;    // Place against right edge.
        m_velocityX = -m_velocityX;  // Reverse direction.
    }

    if (m_y < 0) {                 // if we're at top
        m_y       = 0;
        m_velocityY = -m_velocityY;

    } else if (m_y > m_bottomBound) { // if we're at bottom
        m_y       =  m_bottomBound;
        m_velocityY = -m_velocityY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the velocity must be integral, just update the values to the floor of the floating-point calculation.  So to reduce velocity by 10%:

```
m_velocityX = floor(m_velocityX * 0.9);
```

You might want to do something fancier someday, but this seems simple and workable.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the ball speed as `velocity` and `angle`.
Also, every variable mentioned should be `float` or `double`.

Then everything will be easier, and much more accurate.

The algorithm will then be:

```
float x,y,velocity,angle
int ix,iy;
...
{
    if(y<0) angle=-angle;
    ... etc, etc.

    velocity*=0.95;
    x+=velocity*cos(angle);
    y+=velocity*sin(angle);

    // And you get your precious integers ...
    ix=floor(x);
    iy=floor(y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. ix and iy must be integers because ix and iy are the coordinates and coordinates can't be double or float. Because I will cast them to integer no need to call floor function.if(y<0) angle=-angle; this one worked but I couldn't do the part that if (x<0). Normally angle = 180 - angle; but it didn't worked. what should i do

Answer (score 0):

> if the velocity is 9 and I want to decrease it by 10% I cant do it "9 * 0.1" because it has to be an integer

1. scale up the velocity and coordinates (multiply eg by 256 or shift left by eg 8)
2. calculate decrease for scaled up velocity "9 * 256 / 10"
3. calculate new (scaled up) position and velocity
4. scale down

About like below...

```
Ball move(Ball ball, Border border, Tracer tracer) {
    tracer.trace("scale stuff up to handle acceleration = velocity / 8");
    Scale scale = new Scale(256);
    Int2D position = scale.up(ball.position);
    Velocity velocity = new Velocity(scale.up(ball.velocity));

    tracer.trace("calculate acceleration as scaled up velocity / 8";
    Int2D acceleration = new Scale(8).down(velocity);

    tracer.trace("Move the ball at the given velocity");
    position = position.plus(velocity);

    tracer.trace("slow down velocity");
    velocity = velocity.slowDown(acceleration);

    tracer.trace("scale back down to original");
    ball = new Ball(scale.down(position), new Velocity(scale.down(velocity)));

    tracer.trace("adjust if ball hits the borders and change the way");
    return border.reflectIfNeeded(ball);
}

interface Tracer { void trace(String msg); }

class Scale {
    final int scale; // better be power of 2
    Scale(int scale) { this.scale = scale; }
    Int2D up(Int2D src) { return new Int2D(src.x * scale, src.y * scale); }
    Int2D down(Int2D src) { return new Int2D(src.x / scale, src.y / scale); }
} // Scale

class Border {
    final Int2D topLeft, bottomRight;
    Border(Int2D topLeft, Int2D bottomRight) {
        this.topLeft = topLeft;
        this.bottomRight = bottomRight;
    }
    Ball reflectIfNeeded(Ball ball) {
        if (within(ball)) { return ball; }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet implemented");
    }
    private boolean within(Ball ball) {
        return within(ball.position.x, topLeft.x, bottomRight.x)
                && within(ball.position.y, topLeft.y, bottomRight.y);
    }
    private boolean within(int value, int min, int max) {
        return value > min && value < max;
    }
} // Border

class Ball {
    final Int2D position;
    final Velocity velocity;
    Ball(Int2D position, Velocity velocity) {
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }
} // Ball

class Velocity extends Int2D {
    Velocity(Int2D src) { super(src.x, src.y); }
    Velocity slowDown(Int2D acceleration) {
        return new Velocity(this.minus(acceleration));
    }
    Velocity reflectX() { return new Velocity(new Int2D(-x, y)); }
    Velocity reflectY() { return new Velocity(new Int2D(x, -y)); }
} // Velocity

class Int2D {
    final int x, y;
    Int2D(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
    Int2D plus(Int2D other) { return new Int2D(x + other.x, y + other.y); }
    Int2D minus(Int2D other) { return new Int2D(x - other.x, y - other.y); }
} // Int2D
```